# Apply fgruler on the whole document and change it to inch

Tags: margins, rules

I want to apply fgruler on my whole document, such that every page has top, left, right, and bottom ruler (if it's not possible, top ruler and left ruler only is ok). Just like when i'm using M. W@rd, it helps me to measure vspace. But i want the measurement is in inch instead of cm.

Here, my MWE only produces ruler on the first page only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=5cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[type=none]{fgruler}
\begin{document}
    \fgruler{upperleft}{0cm}{0cm}
    \blinddocument  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to insert top/bottom/left/right rules on each page manually, since you may want to tweak the direction of the rulers individually.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[type=none]{fgruler}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

% Top-to-bottom, left-to-right
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\ruler[in]{downright}{\paperheight}}
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\ruler[in]{rightup}{\paperwidth}}
  \AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\ruler[in]{rightdown}{\paperwidth}}}
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{\ruler[in]{downleft}{\paperheight}}}
}%
% Bottom-to-top, left-to-right
%\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
%  \AtPageLowerLeft{\ruler[in]{upright}{\paperheight}}
%  \AtPageLowerLeft{\ruler[in]{rightup}{\paperwidth}}
%  \AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\ruler[in]{rightdown}{\paperwidth}}}
%  \AtPageLowerLeft{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{\ruler[in]{upleft}{\paperheight}}}
%}%

\begin{document}

\blinddocument  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful work!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[type=user,unit=in]{fgruler}
\fgrulerdefuserin{\fgrulertype{in}{upperleft}\fgrulertype{in}{lowerright}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument  
\end{document}
```

[image]